# How did the Starliner get the wrong time?

Tags: atlas-v, avionics, cst-100

According to [NASA's blog](https://blogs.nasa.gov/commercialcrew/2020/02/07/nasa-shares-initial-findings-from-boeing-starliner-orbital-flight-test-investigation/), one of the problems with the failed Starliner mission was

> An error with the Mission Elapsed Timer (MET), which incorrectly polled time from the Atlas V booster nearly 11 hours prior to launch.

This raises a number of questions. NASA never enumerates how the Atlas got the wrong time. The question I have **is it common for payloads to get the time from the booster**, or is Starliner just an outlier?

Comment: I, too, have so many questions....  I hope this eventually is explained.

Comment: Not an answer but a reason to ask the booster for time is that the booster is the thing all the pad hardware will be connecting to, and the guidance system is the bit that should be the most authoritative/trusted data source for time/position etc. This assumes a random commercial payload of course, and possibly should not be true for a manned craft.

Comment: The reports to date are rather cursory, not much beyond that this timing error occurred. I suspect that the problem wasn't so much that the Starliner polled the Atlas V regarding Mission Elapsed Time 11 hours prior to launch, but that the Starliner didn't regularly poll the Atlas V regarding MET starting 11 hours prior to launch, continuing the regular polling up to (and perhaps beyond) launch. The problem is that MET has holds and resets up until launch occurs.